# Is it possible to run uipv6 without contiki?

Tags: contiki

As we all known, uipv6 is integrated into contiki-os.

So, Is it possible to separate uipv6 from contiki-os? So that we can run the uipv6 in a platform without an OS.

Answer (score 0):

Contiki-OS is completely modular. If you want to use only uip-ipv6 stack.Yes, you can. Have a look at the following link: http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01790.html for uip-ipv6 specific features.